# Use of undefined constant post - assumed 'post' - php code with html

Tags: php, laravel

Do you know why this code `"<a href="{{route('posts.show', ['id' => 'post.id', 'slug' => post.slug])}}" class="btn btn-primary text-white">More</a>"` in the code below shows Use of undefined constant post - assumed 'post'?

```
    $.each(result, function(index, post) {
            newPosts += '<div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 mb-4">\n' +
'                        <div class="card box-shaddow">\n' +
+'                            <div class="card-body">\n' +
+'                                <h5 class="card-title h6 font-weight-bold text-heading-blue">'+post.name+'</h5>\n' +
+'                            </div>\n' +
'                            <div class="card-footer d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">\n' +
'                                 <a href="{{route('posts.show', ['id' => 'post.id', 'slug' => post.slug])}}" class="btn btn-primary text-white">More</a>

'       <span class="font-weight-bold font-size-sm text-heading-blue"> </span>\n' +
'                            </div>\n' +
'                        </div>\n' +
'                    </div>';
        });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP parse/syntax errors; and how to solve them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Comment: What happens when you `{{ dd(route('posts.show', ['id' => 'post.id', 'slug' => post.slug])) }}`

Comment: Wait a minute.  You've marked this as PHP, but that looks like Javascript/jQuery.

Comment: @PatrickQ He is probably doing `$('body').append(newPosts)` kind of thing

Comment: You're attempting to use JavaScript in a PHP block. The PHP block is rendered before the JavaScript ever runs, so it's not possible to do it the way you have it now. You can try putting dummy values in the id and slug variables and doing a replace on the string in the JavaScript before you use the newPosts variable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use your Javascript `post` object as a variable in a call to Blade's `route()` function. Blade will render the template on the server before sending it to the browser, whereas your Javascript code gets executed by your visitor on their computer much later.

One option is to let Blade fill a variable that you can use in Javascript, using dummy values:

```
var placeholder = "{{route('posts.show', ['id' => 123, 'slug' => 'demo-slug'])}}";

$.each(result, function(index, post) {
    var url = placeholder.replace(123, post.id).replace('demo-slug', post.slug);

    newPosts += '[...]'
             +  '<a href="' + url + '" class="btn btn-primary text-white">More</a>'
             +  '[...]';
});
```

Which values you use as placeholders depends on what your route looks like and which validations are used (if any). Just make sure you use a placeholder text that is not already part of your URI.